# Select currency on Checkout - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency, checkout

I've been using the [WooCommerce Currency Switcher](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/) on my store, however the currency does not follow through the checkout.

If there a way for users to select a currency when they enter the checkout?

So, the price will display £ on shop, but on checkout, they can choose a currency to pay in.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue, the answer annoyingly is that you can only output Realmags currency changer on pages with a product in them. 
A very hacky solution is to include a product in your footer and hide it with CSS.

footer.php

```
<?php echo '<div class="hidden">'.do_shortcode('[product id="<ID OF YOUR PRODUCT HERE>"]').'</div>'; ?>
```

styles.css

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: How would '[product id=<...>"]' apply currency switcher on the checkout? Surely that only works for one product?

Comment: All pages with products show the currency switcher next to the menu or wherever you have put it, when you use it to change the currency it changes the currency in the checkout and cart

Comment: It does not carry the currency over to the cart. I have Euro selected throughout, see Euro in the Cart page, but on Checkout, it reverts back to Pound.

Comment: In the plugin settings do you have ''Is multiple allowed' set to to 'Yes'?